# Calling a function using zend framework

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework

I am currently using zend framework and working with jquery and php. Trying to implement an autocheck username availability.

For the following code, I need to call my user_availability.php which is in my controller folder. I did /controllers/user_availability, ../user_availability but it doesnt call that page. Can anyone help?

```
$.post("user_availability.php",{ user_name:$(this).val() } ,function(data)
```

Comment: Could you provide additional info. How is user_availability.php structured? Perhaps you can post the contents of that file.

Answer (score 0):

if you truely want to call a plain php file with zend framework, then you need to put it inside your public folder and call it as /user_availability.php but it should almost certainly be better to make user-availability an action of one of your controllers

Comment: So if let say I have a checkcontroller.php located in my controller and my useravailability is a function in that page. How do i call it?

$.post("checkcontroller.php", {user_name:$(this).val()} , function(data) ? 

Because this doesnt work either..

Comment: could you post a code snippet of your controllers and/or your zend app layout?

Comment: class UsercheckController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
  
 public function indexAction() {  
  $view = Zend_Registry::get('view');  
  $view->render('register2.tpl');
  $users = new Users();

  $username = $_POST['username'];

  require_once 'Zend/Db.php';
  $db2 = Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_Mysql', array(
   'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
   'username' => 'roseadmin',
   'password' => 'test123',
   'dbname'   => 'roseuser',
   'port' => '3306'
  ));
  
  if($users->checkUnique($_POST['username'])){
  echo "fail";
  
                      
 }


 
}

}

Comment: The layout of my zend app is 

1) /application,
    1.1) /default,
         1.1.1) /config
         1.1.2) /controllers
         1.1.3) /models
         1.1.4) /views

Comment: my code which is trying to call the controller is in views folder. thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

Look into Action and View Helpers (depending on where you want to call the script from). Action Helpers can be called from controllers and may be kept in a .../project/library.

From a view you can call a custom View Helper you've written and stored in .../projectname/application/view/helpers.

You may want to restructure your code to fit better within the framework but simply creating a helper that requires (includes) your .php script should work.

[View helpers (Survive the Deep End)](http://survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0/setting.the.design.with.zend.view.zend.layout.html.5.and.yahoo.user.interface.library#zfbook.setting.the.design.with.zend.view.zend.layout.html.5.and.yahoo.user.interface.library.zend.view.object.oriented.templating.view.helpers)

[Action helpers (from the manual):](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html)

Comment: I dont quite understand. My code that is trying to call the controller is in the view folder.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're making a page request to a non-controller item. Anytime you make a request in Zend Framework, it will attempt to match the URL of the request to a route in the system, which corresponds to a controller action. All of this is handled via your application's `index.php` file - the only way to serve a different php file directly would be through your public folder.

My suggestion is to create a controller action that checks for an Ajax request and returns something in your format of choice (XML, json) (rather than rendering an HTML template).

```
public function userAvailableAction() 
{
   if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) { 
      // check user availability
      $this->_helper->json($data);
   }
```

}

Comment: I did create the controller action. But it's just not calling it. I'm calling from the view folder and that template is using .tpl. Does it matters?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I found the solution to it.

You just need to put the function in the controller page and call the function name.

e.g:

```
$.post("check",{ user_name:$(this).val() } ,function(data)
```

Then in your controller file checkusername availability make sure you add the check function.

Answer (score 0):

my controller page is as follows the code:

```
class RegisterController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
    public function checkAction(){
        $users = new Users();
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        if($users->checkUnique($_POST['username'])){
            echo "fail";
        }           
}
```

In this case, the checkUnique is just an sql statement in my model controller to check if the username exist.

For my jquery code it is:

```
$("#username").blur(function(){
    //remove all the class add the messagebox classes and start fading
    $("#msgbox").removeClass().addClass('messagebox').text('Checking...').fadeIn("slow");
    //check the username exists or not from ajax
    $.post("check",{ user_name:$(this).val() } ,function(data){
        if(data=='no'){ //if username not avaiable
            $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function(){ //start fading the messagebox
                //add message and change the class of the box and start fading
                $(this).html('This User name Already exists').addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900,1);
           });
        }else {
         $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function(){  //start fading the messagebox
                //add message and change the class of the box and start fading
                $(this).html('Username available to register').addClass('messageboxok').fadeTo(900,1);
            });
        } 
    });
});
```

I got this example from this link:

http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/04/check-username-available-ajax-php-jquery.html. Do take a look at it. I hope it helps. =)